# Replacing one line of code due to php 7 with a (shell) script

Tags: php, apache, sh, centos6, php-7

So with PHP 7.0 came some issues. Most notably w3 totalcaching is now causing an error that is spamming my httpd error logs.

```
Tue May 17 04:11:50.865647 2016] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 2554:tid 139695893694208] [client 195.154.181.168:59106] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning:  Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /home/x/domains/x/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3464\n', referer: http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html
```

The fix is rather easy https://github.com/gadelkareem/wp-w3-total-cache/commit/e71030e89f4cd666742ae2ec39451782beb42f3a, but I have to do this for about 12 sites. And possibly again when the plugin is updated.

The file is always here (* is variable user and domain related folder):

```
/home/*/domains/*/public_html/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/lib/W3/Plugin/TotalCache.php
```

Is there a way I can safely script this?

Answer (score 1):

On github, user pratham2003 has the [same problem as you and propose](https://github.com/gadelkareem/wp-w3-total-cache/commit/e71030e89f4cd666742ae2ec39451782beb42f3a#commitcomment-14957687) the following [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) command to apply the patch:

```
sed -i.bak 's/function ob_callback(&/function ob_callback(/g' /path/to/public_html/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/lib/W3/Plugin/TotalCache.php
```

The `-i.bak` option can be skip to prevent a backup file from being created.

You can then apply the patch locally and write a script that update the file on each of your servers or ssh on each server and apply the sed command on each server.

You can also maintain a forked plugin and install from this plugin.

But the best will be that the upstream maintainer do himself the modification.

Comment: _"sed is a stream editor. A stream editor is used to perform basic text transformations on an input stream (a file or input from a pipeline). While in some ways similar to an editor which permits scripted edits (such as ed), sed works by making only one pass over the input(s), and is consequently more efficient. But it is sed's ability to filter text in a pipeline which particularly distinguishes it from other types of editors. "_

Sorry I am not familiar with sed. Is this something I have to run on top of my server permanently or is it a one thime single run sort of solution?

Comment: `sed` is a command line tool available on unix like systems like linux, Mac OS X,... If you apply the modification locally, you need sed installed on you local machine. If you want to apply the modification directly on the servers, you need sed installed on all servers.